# Search function doesn't work in PowerApps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I got the search error in my SEARCH function and don't know why. I try different table and it doesn't work also (the data is connecting to SQL). Do you know what happened?

"*the property on this control expects Text values. The rule produces Table values which are incompatible*"

[image]

Comment: Are you searching in textbox? Error says text and table are not compatible

Answer (score 0):

Please try using

```
    Filter(TestAB,TextInput3.Text = 'Member_x0020_First_x0020_Name')
```

instead of the Search function.

Comment: I did it but it won't work

New error is " Invalid argument type." "Location TextInput3.Default"

Comment: Could you try using ' in ' instead of ' = '

Comment: Got it worked. I need to add it in the datatable instead of input box. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would try using a Filter within your search entry. You will want the filter to live inside the search function. Let me know if this works or renders an error. If it renders a new error, please post it so I can ty and solve for you!

Search(Filter(TestAB,TextInput3.Text = 'Member_x0020_First_x0020_Name'))

Comment: Got it worked. I need to add it in the datatable instead of input box. Thank you!